# Flask send_file() giving error TypeError: send_file() missing 1 required positional argument: 'environ'

Tags: python, flask, flask-sqlalchemy

So I am new to flask and have been working on developing a little web app locally on my computer. I haven't run into too many issues, but I have not been able to get my webpage to return a csv file when clicking on a link. I get an error stating that the environ variable is missing, to my understanding I can set this to be a server that then serves up the document, however, I am hoping to just do this all locally on my machine.

```
@app.route('/sessions/csv_file')
def get_csv_file():
   return send_file('./sessions.csv',mimetype='csv',as_attachment=True, 
   download_name='sessions.csv')
```

edit:This code gives me the following error:
TypeError: send_file() missing 1 required positional argument: 'environ'

I was given advice to try using my app as the environ variable:

```
app = Flask(__name__)    
@app.route('/sessions/csv_file')
    def get_csv_file():
       return send_file('./sessions.csv',mimetype='csv',as_attachment=True, 
       download_name='sessions.csv', environ=app)
```

But this give me the following error:
TypeError: get() takes 2 positional arguments but 3 were given

I have also tried this with send_directory() and run into the same environ error. If anyone is able to point me in the right direction that would be greatly appreciated!

edit: send_file() is an import

```
from werkzeug.utils import send_file
```

Comment: Have you created your own function named `send_file`?

Comment: No send_file is an import: from werkzeug.utils import send_file.
I got this while looking up solutions to send a file from a flask app.

Comment: `send_file() is an import` -> that's the wrong `send_file`.  Use `from flask import send_file`

Comment: @snakecharmerb that was it thanks! I think someone had said flask uses that import so didn't even think to use flasks version of it.

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in your post's comments there is two version of `send_file` in flask.

one from `werkzeug.utils` which you can import like:

```
from werkzeug.utils import send_file
```

another from `flask` package as

```
from flask import send_file
```

`send_file` from flask package actually calls `send_file` of werkzeug.utils with `request.environ`. Here is the flask's `send_file` implementation:

```
return werkzeug.utils.send_file(
    **_prepare_send_file_kwargs(
        path_or_file=path_or_file,
        environ=request.environ,
        mimetype=mimetype,
        as_attachment=as_attachment,
        download_name=download_name,
        attachment_filename=attachment_filename,
        conditional=conditional,
        etag=etag,
        add_etags=add_etags,
        last_modified=last_modified,
        max_age=max_age,
        cache_timeout=cache_timeout,
    )
```

So to fix this error replace `send_file` from werkzeug with flask version

```
from flask import send_file
```

Or assign your `send_file`'s last parameter(`environ`) with `request.environ` as below:

```
return send_file('./sessions.csv',mimetype='csv',as_attachment=True, 
   download_name='sessions.csv', environ=request.environ)
```

However there is still a little difference:
relative paths of flask's `send_file` are based on root path(if you are using flask blueprints it will be the current python package). But werkzeug paths refers to execution root(parent of the current python package usually).